# Use sshpass to scp files from two remote hosts

Tags: linux, scp, sshpass

I have the following problem. I have sshpass installed on Server A.

I have files on Server B that I need to copy to Server C. (Servers B and C don't have sshpass installed, and are in another network.)

I already have a script that copies this files from Server A to Server B, than from Server A to Server C, and so on (there are other servers...)

What I want is to use sshpass from Server A to scp files from Server B to Server C.

Thank you